# Copy folder to build directory Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build, visual-studio-2017

How do I go about to make Visual Studio add a folder from my project into the build directory (for example \x64\Release)? I have a folder for images that I want to be included when I build my application so that they can easily be accessed in relation to the executable's location. The problem with doing it manually is that I have to copy it over manually for both my debug and release folders instead of keeping it all compact withing my project. It also helps with uploading to github.

So is there any way to do this? And if so, how?

Comment: This appears to be an installer issue.  You may want to install an installer plug-in (add-in) and check the destination folder structure.

Comment: Would be easier to answer if you show the project structure, but one simple way is defining a post-build event in the project properties like `xcopy /Y $(ProjectDir)/images/*.bmp $(OutDir)` should do the trick

Comment: This is a build tools issue. Not a C++ issue.

Comment: @JesperJuhl The problem is specific to C++ however. I already found solutions for C# where Visual Studio behaves differently.

Comment: Technically it's related to the build system for C++ as used by MSBuild and/or Visual Studio, that's way more specific than 'C++' the language